# PyPy does not work on MacOS 10.9.5

Tags: macos, macports, pypy, libssl

I'm trying to install PyPy on MacOS 10.9.5.
As a first try I downloaded a tarball containing the binary files directly from the official website, unpacked it and launched `pypy` inside bash. I got this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/<MY_USER>/opt/pypy2-v5.10.0-osx64/bin//libpypy-c.dylib
Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

So I tried installing openssl with `sudo port install openssl` but the error remained. I also tried installing pypy via `sudo port install pypy` but I got the same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception on macOS – libraries on macOS are not referenced by name only, but by absolute path. For this reason, the MacPorts OpenSSL installed in /opt/local does not fulfill the requirement of the library shipped with PyPy, because it expects the library in /usr/local/opt/openssl.

I'm quoting an email from myself on the macports-users list a few days ago, which explains the details:

> macOS libraries are referenced from binaries using their absolute path.
>
> At a technical level, when you link a binary with, for example, -lcurl on
>   the command line, the linker will locate libcurl.dylib in the search paths
>   you've given on the command line (that should be -L/opt/local/lib for use
>   with MacPorts). It will then read the library id from the file. For our
>   example of MacPorts' libcurl, this is:
>
> ```
> $> otool -D /opt/local/lib/libcurl.dylib
> /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
> ```
>
> This path will then be copied into the linked binary. You can verify this
>   with the MacPorts curl binary:
>
> ```
> $> otool -L /opt/local/bin/curl | grep libcurl
> /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
> ```
>
> When you run /opt/local/bin/curl, the loader reads this table and locates
>   this file using its absolute path. Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH overrides this
>   and attempts to locate a file with the given basename in the directories
>   given in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but if the library and the binary have been
>   built correctly (and not moved) you should never have to set it.
>
> Of course this makes your binaries non-relocatable. If you want to relocate
>   binaries, you can use relative paths using the special variables @loader_path,
>   @executable_path and @rpath. See the dylibbundler port, which largely
>   automates this if you built your binaries with the -headerpad_max_install_names
>   linker flag (which MacPorts does by default).

To work around your problem, you could set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH and hope that the libraries are binary compatible (which they may or may not be) or use `install_name_tool -change` (which does the same but in the file rather the environment). You should, however, ask whoever gave you this binary how they expect you to run it and where to get the matching OpenSSL library.